# Macro-button does not work like the rest

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a Worksheet with a lot of different macros (approx. 20) and most of them are being successfully activated by buttons (Form controls).

My last macro is not being activated properly by the button. It looks like the macro is being run partially and then stops, but without error. 
If I push the "play" button in the visual basic environment it works fine.

I viewed the code behind the button and the macro is assigned correctly. I changed the button, I changed the name of the macro (no blank spaces etc.) but it did not help.

The rest still works fine, so no updates etc. involved.
Anybody have a clue what could be the issue ? The code I am using is the following:

```
Sub find_overdue()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lr&, i&, k&

    k = 1
    Worksheets("search results").Range("A:F").ClearContents
    Worksheets("search results").Range("A:F").ClearFormats

    Worksheets("overdue").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate

    lr = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    k = 1

    For i = 1 To lr
        If Cells(i, "D").Value = "OVERDUE" Then
            Cells(i, "A").Copy
            Worksheets("search results").Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            Cells(i, "B").Copy
            Worksheets("search results").Range("B" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            Cells(i, "C").Copy
            Worksheets("search results").Range("C" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            Cells(i, "D").Copy
            Worksheets("search results").Range("D" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Worksheets("search results").Columns("A:F").AutoFit
    Worksheets("search results").Activate

    Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

    Range("A1") = "Tag & Work"
    Range("B1") = "Last Date"
    Range("C1") = "Due Date"
    Range("D1") = "status"  

    Worksheets("search results").Range("A1:F1").Font.Bold = True
    Worksheets("search results").Range("A1:F1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

    Columns("A:D").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("search results").sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("search results").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
      "C:C"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
      xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("search results").sort
        .SetRange Range("A:D")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Worksheets("search results").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
End Sub
```

So as you can see, I am changing through two sheets ("overdue" and "search results") thus the sheet activation, my button is on a third Sheet.

Comment: Try using the button from the ActiveX Controls? You have given very little information for us to provide a concrete answer...

Comment: @Xabier I would stay away from ActiveX where ever possible! Also I see no case where this would help, because he said the macro runs partially the button cannot be the issue it must be the macro itself. **@ user36510** Please [edit] your question and add the VBA code (macro) which is not working properly. Make use of breakpoints and step-by-step execution (F8) do debug on which line it gets aborted. It's almost impossible to answer your question without seeing the code which aborts.

Comment: @ Peh: That is the point, the code works fine. No error or debugging necessary, no abort. It just finished much quicker and with only a part of the info I am trying to filter. I see only a problem with the link via the button.

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code.**

Comment: @user36510 No it may make a difference if the code is started from an *active sheet* or from a *userform* or from the *VBA run/play button*. Therefore I suggest you show the code. Otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: Ok guys, I posted the code. Hope you can help.

Comment: @Peh What is your preference over ActiveX ? I, from time to time, find myself cursing them.

Comment: @QHarr I would stick to the Form Controls where ever possible. ActiveX crashed my Excel in too many cases and I had several issues I never had with Form Controls.

Comment: @Peh How do you handle the miniature font size? Hoping this info may be of use to OP as well, otherwise i apologise for hijacking the comments somewhat.

Comment: @user36510 I'm pretty sure the issue is that you are using `.Activate` instead of specifying a worksheet for every `Range`. Define a worksheet like `Set ws = Worksheets("SheetName")` and use it for all `Ranges` and `Cells` etc. like `ws.Range()`. There are many tutorials on how to avoid `.Activate`. After that you should not run into any odd issues anymore.

Comment: @QHarr I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean with miniature font size. I think where getting quite off-topic here.

Comment: I was thinking of displayed font in drop down of form combobox. But i will leave it as indeed is wandering off. Apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159968/discussion-between-peh-and-qharr).

Comment: @Peh: It worked. I removed all the .Activate entries and now it is ok. Thanks !

Comment: @user36510 No please don't only remove them! You will also need to specify a concrete worksheet for every `Range` like I said in my comment! Otherwise you will run into other issues.

Comment: @Peh: Yes, I ment that I adapted the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `.Activate` parts and specifying a concrete worksheet for every range should fix it.

Also don't forget to `.ScreenUpdating = True` in the end if you set this `False` in the beginning.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub find_overdue()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lr As Long, i As Long, k As Long

    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Set wsResults = Worksheets("search results")
    With wsResults.Range("A:F")
        .ClearContents
        .ClearFormats
    End If

    Dim wsOverdue As Worksheet
    Set wsOverdue = Worksheets("overdue")
    With wsOverdue
        lr = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        k = 1

        For i = 1 To lr
            If .Cells(i, "D").Value = "OVERDUE" Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Copy
                wsResults.Range("A" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                .Cells(i, "B").Copy
                wsResults.Range("B" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                .Cells(i, "C").Copy
                wsResults.Range("C" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                .Cells(i, "D").Copy
                wsResults.Range("D" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next i

        wsResults.Columns("A:F").AutoFit

        .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
        .Range("A1") = "Tag & Work"
        .Range("B1") = "Last Date"
        .Range("C1") = "Due Date"
        .Range("D1") = "status"

        wsResults.Range("A1:F1").Font.Bold = True
        wsResults.Range("A1:F1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        .Range("B:C").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@" 'instead of B:B and C:C we can use B:C
    End With

    With wsResults.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=wsResults.Range("C:C"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
           Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange wsResults.Range("A:D")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Don't forget to activate screen updating in the end!
End Sub
```